# Balsamiq mockups is deleting my next line in site map

Tags: mockups, mockup-tool, balsamiq

Whenever I add a site map in Balsamiq mockups and edit it by double clicking it, it starts deleting my next line in the options.
For example if I have my site map as follows:

```
INDEX
-NAVIGATION BAR
--LOGO
--HOME 
--ABOUT US
--CORPORATE
--PROJECTS
--CONTACT US
--SEARCH BOX
-CONTENT
-FOOTER
--SOCIAL MEDIA
---TWITTER
---FACEBOOK
---LINKEDIN
---GOOGLE PLUS
---BEHANCE
--ADDRESS/GOOGLE MAP
```

Now, if at any later stage I want to add another social media site between Twitter and Facebook, I start typing between them and it starts deleting all the text below Twitter alphabet by alphabet as I keep typing. Please help.

Comment: Your insert key on your keyboard is either pressed, putting your keyboard in insert mode or it is stuck.